# Capture the output from function in real time python

Tags: python-2.7, output, real-time, capture, sympy

I didn't find quite what I was looking for.

I want to obtain the output (stdout) from a python function in real time.

The actual problem is that I want to plot a graph (with cplot from sympy) with a progress bar in my UI. The argument `verbose` makes cplot output the progress to stdout.

```
sympy.mpmath.cplot(lambda z: z, real, imag, verbose=True)
```

The output would be something like:

```
0 of 71
1 of 71
2 of 71
...
```

And so on.

I want to capture line by line so I can make a progress bar. (I realize this might not be possible without implementing multithreading). I'm using python2.7 (mainly because I need libraries that aren't in python3)

So, ¿How do I achieve that?

Comment: Is there a generator version of `cplot()` that yields some value instead of printing it? If not, here's [several ways to redirect stdout temporarily in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)

Comment: With a generator version would be easier, sadly no.
And for that examples... those redirect the stdout (or I think I could grasp that) but don't let me work with it in parallel. And lastly they're intended for python3.

Comment: 1. they do "let you work with it in parallel" e.g., redirect stdout to a pipe and read it in another thread/process concurrently.  2. Only the very first example is for Python 3 and it is followed immediately by the code that does the same on older versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture stdout by monkeypatching `sys.stdout`. A good way to do it is using a context manager, so that it gets put back when you are done (even if the code raises an exception). If you don't use a context manager, be sure to put the original `sys.stdout` back using a `finally` block.

You'll need an object that is file-like, that takes the input and does what you want with it. Subclassing `StringIO` is a good start. Here's an example of a context manager that captures stdout and stderr and puts them in the result of the bound variable.

```
class CapturedText(object):
    pass

@contextmanager
def captured(disallow_stderr=True):
    """
    Context manager to capture the printed output of the code in the with block

    Bind the context manager to a variable using `as` and the result will be
    in the stdout property.

    >>> from tests.helpers import capture
    >>> with captured() as c:
    ...     print('hello world!')
    ...
    >>> c.stdout
    'hello world!\n'
    """
    import sys

    stdout = sys.stdout
    stderr = sys.stderr
    sys.stdout = outfile = StringIO()
    sys.stderr = errfile = StringIO()
    c = CapturedText()
    yield c
    c.stdout = outfile.getvalue()
    c.stderr = errfile.getvalue()
    sys.stdout = stdout
    sys.stderr = stderr
    if disallow_stderr and c.stderr:
        raise Exception("Got stderr output: %s" % c.stderr)
```

([source](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/tests/helpers.py))

It works as shown in the docstring. You can replace `StringIO()` with your own class that writes the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to monkeypatch `sympy.mpmath.visualization.print`, since `cplot` uses `print` to print the output, and it uses `from __future__ import print_function`.

First, make sure you are using `from __future__ import print_function` if you aren't using Python 3, as this will otherwise be a SyntaxError.

Then something like

```
def progressbar_print(*args, **kwargs):
    # Take *args and convert it to a progress output
    progress(*args)
    # If you want to still print the output, do it here
    print(*args, **kwargs)

sympy.mpmath.visualization.print = progressbar_print
```

You might want to monkeypatch it in a custom function that puts it back, as other functions in that module might use `print` as well. Again, remember to do this using either a context manager or a `finally` block so that it gets put back even if an exception is raised.

Monkeypatching `sys.stdout` is definitely the more standard way of doing this, but I like this solution in that it shows that having `print` as a function can actually be useful.